# JSTL c:url not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm learning Spring MVC. My static resources are successfully mapped using `spring` taglib. But resources are not mapped if i use JSTL `c` taglib.

**Project Structure**

[image]

**web.xml**

[image]

**spring-servlet.xml**

[image]

**main.css**

```
h1{
    color:red;
}
```

**welcome.jsp**

[image]

**output**

[image]

Jquery and main.js is loaded with the `spring` taglib that's why h2 has body, but I don't understand why h1's color is not red?

```
05-May-2017 15:45:24.843 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/basic/public-resources/css/main.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I changed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/public-resources/css/main.css" />'>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />'>
```

IntelliJ is giving me error that the directory is not resolved and the whole directory is red. but when deployed, it works.